# Look for specific word in first row, if found do calculation, if not, go to next sheet in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to implement some VBA code such that if the word, "LowLimit" in the first row.  If found, then carry out the calculations and move to next sheet.  If not found, then go to next sheet.

I have declared the word "LowLimit", `Dim lowLimHdr As String`.  How do implement the `IF...THEN` using this argument before entering into my calculations?

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub ReturnMarginal()
'UpdatebySUPERtoolsforExcel2016
    Dim xOut As Worksheet
    Dim xWb As Workbook
    Dim xWks As Worksheet
    Dim InterSectRange As Range
    Dim lowLimCol As Integer
    Dim hiLimCol As Integer
    Dim measCol As Integer
    Dim lowLimHdr As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xWb = ActiveWorkbook
    For Each xWks In xWb.Sheets
    xRow = 1
    With xWks
        FindString = "LowLimit"
        'If
        .Cells(xRow, 16) = "Meas-LO"
        .Cells(xRow, 17) = "Meas-Hi"
        .Cells(xRow, 18) = "Min Value"
        .Cells(xRow, 19) = "Marginal"
        LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        lowLimCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("LowLimit", xWks.Range("1:1"), 0)
        hiLimCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("HighLimit", xWks.Range("1:1"), 0)
        measLimCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("MeasValue", xWks.Range("1:1"), 0)
        .Range("P2:P" & LastRow).Formula = "=" & Cells(2, measLimCol).Address(False, False) & "-" & Cells(2, lowLimCol).Address(False, False)
        .Range("Q2:Q" & LastRow).Formula = "=" & Cells(2, hiLimCol).Address(False, False) & "-" & Cells(2, measLimCol).Address(False, False)
        .Range("R2").Formula = "=min(P2,Q2)"
        .Range("R2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("R2:R" & LastRow)

        .Range("S2").Formula = "=IF(AND(R2>=-3, R2<=3), ""Marginal"", R2)"
        .Range("S2").AutoFill Destination:=.Range("S2:S" & LastRow)

     End With
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'turn it back on

 Next xWks
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
If Not xWks.Rows(1).Find(FindString) Is Nothing Then
    ' do your calculations
End If
```

Comment: Since the VBA Find inherits parameters from the worksheet Find, there are typically more than just a **what:=** parameter supplied in order to guard against a previous user Find fouling up the operation.

Comment: @Jeeped what puzzles me most is how this is useful since the OP code needs to catch those columns and *use* them. It seems that this answer suggests to do the search twice: once to see if it is the headers are there, and then to find the columns. Beats me ...

Comment: Agreed. If you need three things, then gather all three and check to see if they are all there. Relying on *'if one is there then the other two should be'* is just asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2):

You need to dim your variables `lowLimCol`, `HighLimCol` and `measCol` as `Variant`s because in the case of no match, `Application.Match` returns an error variant, otherwise a number that represents the index of the found column.

```
Dim lowLimCol. hiLimCol, measCol

lowLimCol = Application.Match("LowLimit", xWks.Range("1:1"), 0)
hiLimCol = Application.Match("HighLimit", xWks.Range("1:1"), 0)
measLimCol = Application.Match("MeasValue", xWks.Range("1:1"), 0)

' Check if all these columns were found in the header to proceed:

If Not (IsError(lowLimCol) Or IsError(highLimCol) Or IsError(measLimCol)) Then
  '
  ' You calculations here
  '
End If
```

p.s. the variable `lowLimHdr` is your code seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could also keep them declared as integers and then use

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("1:1"), LowLimHdr) > 0 Then
    ' do all my calcuations in here
End If
```

That's assuming that any sheet with "LowLimit" will definitely have the other headers too, otherwise previous answer is better for error catching.

**EDIT:** In a similar vein to A.S.H's answer, to do full error catching in case any of the headers are missing you'd need a triple check:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("1:1"), "LowLimit") > 0 And _ 
Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("1:1"), "HighLimit") > 0 And _
Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("1:1"), "MeasValue") > 0 Then
    ' do all my calcuations in here
End If
```

Comment: once "LowLimit" is not found, it means the others will not be  present so move to next sheet.

Comment: It was just a worry that it may find "LowLimit" and try to do the rest of the calculations but cause an error if a user had accidentally deleted "HighLimit". I edited my answer to cover that, but I believe A.S.H's answer is more robust and seems like better coding practice.